# Process a call in wpf Application in Main thread

Tags: c#, wpf, thread-safety, dispatcher

My wpf application connects to my legacy application through communication pipes. WPF application allows user to plot locations on map using a button on the interface. So when user clicks the button on WPF application user interface, a pipe message is sent to legacy application to allow user to plot locations on map. When user plot locations on map using mouse, the coordinates are sent back to wpf application using the 2 way communication pipe. When my wpf application receives the coordinates, it needs to process and perform the workflows accordingly. There might appear some errors, so application might need to show error message. or in some cases might need to clear collections that were created in Application main thread. So there is a whole branch of code that get executed when coordinates are received.

**How can I bring my WPF application back to Main thread so that when coordinates are received, user actions like showing message box etc.. can be performed?**

**right now I am getting exceptions like "collection was created in a different thread".**

I know I can use this code to show message in Main thread or clear collections

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { PointsCollection.Clear(); })); 

Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { MessageBox.Show("Error"); }));
```

but this wont work in unit testing and also I will have to do this in lot of places. is there a better way?

```
public void PipeClientMessageReceived(int type, string message)
{
    var command = (PipeCommand)type;
    switch (command)
    {
        case PipeCommand.Points:
            {
                string[] tokens = message.Split(':');
                var x = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[0]);
                var y = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[1]);
                SetSlotCoordinates(new Point2D(x, y)); 
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

**SetSlotCoordinates method actually does all the work to process the coordinates. I tried putting this calling in Application.Current.Dispatcher but no success.**

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { SetSlotCoordinates(new Point2D(x, y));  }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the question is not very clear. What issue exists with unit testing that you believe prevents you from using `Dispatcher.Invoke()`? When you tried using `Dispatcer.Invoke()` on the call to `SetSlotCoordinates()`, in what way was there "no success"?

Basically, the use of `Dispatcher.Invoke()` (or its asynchronous sibling, `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` should do the job for you. However, if you're able, I would recommend using the new `async`/`await` pattern.

Without a complete code example, it's impossible to give you the exact code. But it would look something like this:

```
async Task ReceiveFromPipe(Stream pipeStream, int bufferSize)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int byteCount;

    while ((byteCount = await pipeStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)       
    {
        int type;
        string message;

        if (TryCompleteMessage(buffer, byteCount, out type, out message))   
        {
            PipeClientMessageReceived(type, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this technique, and assuming that the `ReceiveFromPipe()` method is called from the UI thread, you will already be on the UI thread when the read from the pipe completes, making everything else "just work".

Note: I've glossed over details such as how exactly you maintain your buffer of incoming data until a complete message is received...I've assumed that's encapsulated in the hypothetical `TryCompleteMessage()` method. The above is for illustration purposes, and of course you'd have to adapt to your own specific code.

Also, you may find it makes more sense to do more of the processing in the background thread, in which case you'd put the actual receive and that processing into a separate `async` method; in that case, that method would still call `ReadAsync()`, but you could call `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the return value of that, so that the switch back to the UI thread didn't happen until that separate `async` method returned. For example:

```
async Task ReceiveFromPipe(Stream pipeStream, int bufferSize)
{
    Action action;

    while ((action = await ReceivePoint2D(pipeStream, bufferSize)) != null)
    {
        action();
    }
}

async Task<Action> ReceivePoint2D(Stream pipeStream, int bufferSize)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int byteCount;

    while ((byteCount = await pipeStream
        .ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false)) > 0)       
    {
        int type;
        string message;

        if (TryCompleteMessage(buffer, byteCount, out type, out message))   
        {
            return PipeClientMessageReceived(type, message);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public Action PipeClientMessageReceived(int type, string message)
{
    var command = (PipeCommand)type;
    switch (command)
    {
        case PipeCommand.Points:
            {
                string[] tokens = message.Split(':');
                var x = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[0]);
                var y = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[1]);
                return () => SetSlotCoordinates(new Point2D(x, y)); 
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

In the above example, the asynchronous code does everything except the call to `SetSlotCoordinates()`. For that, it wraps the call in an `Action` delegate, returning that to the UI thread where the UI thread can then invoke it. Of course, you don't have to return an `Action` delegate; that was just the most convenient way I saw to adapt the code you already have. You can return any value or object and let the UI thread handle it appropriately.

Finally, with respect to all of the above, note that nowhere in the code is an explicit dependency on the UI thread. While I'm not sure what issue you are concerned with respect to unit testing, the above should be much more easily adapted to unit testing scenarios where no `Dispatcher` is available or you'd prefer not to use it for some reason.

If you want to stick with explicit use of `Dispatcher`, then you should be more specific about what exactly isn't working.